# How do I open Chrome from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, hyperlink

How do I open Chrome using a specified "user profile" from Excel?

For example. I have an Excel spreadsheet with many links such as:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\File1.txt
C:\Users\User\Desktop\File2.html
C:\Users\User\Desktop\File3.mhtml
```

Comment: Do you what to click those file names on the sheet to open them, or use VBA?

Comment: I think using vba

Answer (score 0):

To open Google Chrome from Excel VBA, use the VBA.Shell command / method. Assuming Google Chrome is indeed installed on the devices you will run this from, try the following. You will need to tweak this for your specific purposes.

```
Sub OpenBrowserFiles()
    Dim strGCPath As String, strUrlFile As String

    'strGCPath: could be in Program Files, or AppData\Local for the device user
    strGCPath = "Path\To\Google\chrome.exe"

    'strUrlFile: path of file on the device you want to opn in chrom
    strUrlFile = "file:///path/to/file/on/device/the_file.html"

    'Note: the profile name, you can make this a variable too. 
    VBA.Shell strGCPath & " --profile-directory=Person1 " & " -url " & strUrlFile

End Sub
```

Also, consider if you have a list of files, like in your example, loop through  cells or range object, and be aware of how many instances of Google Chrome you may open.

**Edit: Open File-Link in an Excel Worksheet by clicking on it**
**@ffredy55**

Whether you have inserted or formatted the cells as a hyperlink, or left the format as text, you may need to trap the click event  within a specified range, so you can open the file-link using a specified browser, in your case Google Chrome. I'm sure there are other ways.

In your VBA editor, open the code sheet for the worksheet your file-links are on. Note, this is a simplified example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rngClickable As Excel.Range
    Dim strGCPath As String
    
    ' Important! Where is Google Chrome installed at. 
    ' Could it be in your AppData\Local folder ???
    strGCPath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

    ' Define the range of clickable cells you require.
    ' Note: "A2:A4" will also work (from your example)
    Set rngClickable = Me.Range("B2:B4")

    ' Check if where you click is strictly in the range where your file-links are in
    If Not (Excel.Application.Intersect(rngClickable, Target) Is Nothing) Then

        ' The condition is met, launch Google Chrome with the URL passed.
        VBA.Shell strGCPath & " -url " & VBA.CStr(Target.Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

If you want a particular profile when launcing Google Chrome,

```
VBA.Shell strGCPath & "--profile-directory=Person1" & " -url " & VBA.CStr(Target.Value)
```

I hope this gives you a push start for what you want to do. Also, take note of Hannu's comment.

Comment: `strGCPath = "start "+chr(34)+"launched from excel"+chr(34)` makes this code general, i.e. chrome, Firefox or edge will launch - if either of them is set as the preferred browser. No need to have a "path\to\google\..." defined, the chrome-specific parameters needs to go though. But then it will launch e.g. Word docs, Powerpoints or whatever in the same style as a double-click on the Desktop or in File explorer...

Comment: If I have a list of files (hyperlinks) in Excel column, and I want to open hyperlinks in Google Chrome?

Comment: Example: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkw4c.png)

Comment: njc, How Make Excel open hyperlinks with non-default browser (Google Chrome)? [My Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkw4c.png). Sorry for my English.

Comment: @ffredy55 I have edited my answer, hope it gives you some idea.